# How to access the web-application hosted on the another Farm using SharePoint 2010 Management Shell?

Tags: development, powershell, cmdlets

I am trying to access the web-application that is hosted on the another SharePoint 2010 Farm using SharePoint 2010 Management Shell cmdlets but it is failing with the below error message

```
$spsite = Get-SPSite http://demoserver:8080<br/>
Get-SPSite : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url: http://demoserver:8080.
At line:1 char:21
+ $spsite = Get-SPSite <<<<  http://demoserver:8080
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletGetSite:SPCmdletGetSite) [Get-SPSite], SPCm
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetSite
```

same account is used as a FARM account in both the Farms.

Even, I tried with the below powershell script also failed.

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::Loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.SharePoint")

$spsite=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite]("http://demoserver:8080")
```

Is that mean that we can't access the web-application hosted on another Farm?

Comment: This seems to be something to do with double-hobbing..Ref:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg550867.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to enable PowerShell remoting: [Enable-PSRemoting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819498.aspx)

You'll want to use these commands as well:

[Get-Credential](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315327.aspx)

[Enable-WSManCredSSP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819517.aspx)

[Invoke-Command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347578.aspx)

Here's a [blog post](http://www.sharepointdoug.com/2010/02/remoting-with-powershell-in-sharepoint.html) that describes the steps.